# How to have multiple singleton instance when user regenerate the data structure in application?

Tags: singleton, backgroundworker

I have an application which uses back ground worker(bw) and tasks.

I have one singleton instance in this app..which contains most of the common info about that instance of application. I have different **agents** listed in my app..and if I switch to different agent, **i have to build entire data structure** (models/viewmodels/DTOs)

Lets say, for agent "a" one of the bw is spawned...and it uses the above mentioned singleton instance...

Soon I switch to agent "b"...so in my app, i create new data structure for aganet "b". But uses the same singleton instance.

If I change any property in this singleton instance...there is a chance that the new value will be used by bw spawned for agent "a".

Can somebody help me to overcome this situation?

Can I have different singleton instance for different agents ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT : Any different approach if you can tell me it would be great.**

Answer (score 2):

A singleton, by definition, can only exist once. If you want different settings for each user, you will need to use a different architecture. See http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton for more information about singletons.

Comment: actually when i switch agent, it is almost like different app. And yes I am looking for different approach, that why i posted the question here.

Comment: maybe make them objects which you store in the session. more details are necessary.

Comment: this is a desktop app, not web app.